# How can I pull a named item out of the ControlTemplate when a Presenter is creating the view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, controltemplate

I am using the Model-View-Presenter-ViewModel pattern. I am creating a view in the presenter. I would like to pull out a part of the view by name. Specifically I'd like to get the PART_Track of a Slider. However, I absolutely cannot get Template.FindName to return PART_Track! I've tried calling it after the Slider has loaded but it is still null!?  Is there another event I should wait for to access the template?

Comment: I believe OnApplyTemplate should have fired by the time Loaded fires.

Comment: Ah, you're right. `OnApplyTemplate` is just my go-to "I can't find something in a template" answer.

Comment: `I am using the Model-View-Presenter-ViewModel pattern` - I'm curious to see what that actually means, and what role has a presenter have in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580734.aspx

Comment: Oops, the loaded event fires later on when the control becomes visible and then I am able to pull out the PART.